# Leetcode 652. Find Duplicate Subtrees

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

The question is of finding duplicate subtrees and the approach used is to convert each subtree to a post order tree and compare them.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<TreeNode*> ans;
    unordered_map<string, int> list;
    string helper(TreeNode* root){
        if(!root)return "";
        string cur = helper(root->left)+" "+helper(root->right)+" "+to_string(root->val);
        if(list[cur] == 1)ans.push_back(root);
        list[cur]++;
        return cur;
    }

    vector<TreeNode*> findDuplicateSubtrees(TreeNode* root) {
        helper(root);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

But when I try the same question with mid order traversal it wont work. can someone explain why is that?

I want to know why it is not working with mid order traversal and only with pre and post order strings.

Comment: *"it wont work"* -- from this description, should I infer that when you try mid-order traversal, the output is `42` repeated 42 times? (I'm pretty sure that falls under "won't work". Would you edit your question to more precisely describe your symptom? In addition to describing the symptom, it would be a good idea to include an example of input that gives the wrong result, along with the expected and actual output for that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these two trees:

```
  2           1
 / \           \
1   3           2
                 \
                  3
```

The inorder traversal for both trees would be `1 -> 2 -> 3`. Simply put, inorder traversal won't guarantee uniqueness. That's why your solution returns an incorrect answer.

Using preorder/postorder traversal does not guarantee uniqueness either. If you include "null" nodes in your traversal, then they'll give a unique string for each tree. But even then inorder traversal will [not guarantee uniqueness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/116659).